# HOw to know which slot is calling Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, slot

I have multiple Slots and I have lambda function.

Each time when Lambda function gets called but how to identify that from which slot that is being called .

Comment: Should be part of the input event!? E.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-input-format

Comment: Hi ,in shared link I got : invocationSource – Indicates the action that called the Lambda function. When the source is DialogCodeHook, So I think I will receive the DialogueCodeHook when the Lambda function is called by any slot

Answer (score 0):

you can get the slot details from the event object that comes to the lambda function.
see the request object and its details - SLOT_NAME.